How can I make text overflow without ellipse
I need to display some text that is rotated 90 degrees. The text is inside a container, but when rotated, it's being cut off even though there's enough space in the container for it to be fully visible. This is because there is not enough space for the text when it is horizontal.
Here is the relevant part of my code
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const OverflowTextExample = ({ habit }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.habitCard}>
      <View style={styles.habitLabel}>
        <Text style={styles.habitLabelText}>
          {habit.genre}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  habitCard: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  habitLabel: {
    width: 50, // Adjusted width
    height: 200, // Adjusted height
    backgroundColor: '#DD9211',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'relative',
    overflow: 'visible', // Allows overflow
  },
  habitLabelText: {
    position: 'absolute',
    transform: [{ rotate: "-90deg" }],
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    fontWeight: "700",
    fontSize: 12,
  },
});

I have tried   setting the position to absolute but the text stays the same, I have tried to change the ellipseMode but nothing has worked so far.
This is the desired output
Desired Output
and this is what is happening in my code
I have searched for alternatives for turning off text wrapping and tried setting whiteSpace: 'nowrap' but that didn't work either. Any tips is highly appreciated, thanks!
